Why is the Liar a problem?
I'm sorry, but I can't think of a way to explain my question without first discussing a theory of truth, so please bear with me. It will be easiest to explain in terms of a correspondence theory of truth based on states of affairs, although I don't think this theory or states of affairs are really essential to the point.
A state of affairs or SOA is a way that the world might be--and not necessarily just the physical world but the world of everything, including minds, thoughts, abstract objects, etc. An actual SOA is a way that the world actually is. SOAs are objective entities, independent of human thought (which I find very troubling about the notion of an SOA, but, again, this is just so I can ask my question).
A proposition is a concept of an SOA. That is, a proposition is a content of thought that corresponds to some state of affairs. A proposition is true just in case it corresponds to an actual SOA. Due to limitations of human thought, it is not generally the case that a proposition corresponds with perfect precision to a single exact SOA. For example, the proposition that I have a full tank of gas corresponds with many different SOAs, many different quantities of gas, all within a gallon or so of an absolutely full tank.
A pseudo-proposition is a concept superficially like a proposition, but one that doesn't properly correspond to an SOA.
Examples of pseudo-propositions:
Category error: "The number five is dry.", "My thoughts weigh more than the color green." These don't correspond to a SOA because there is no such possible SOA.
Vagueness: "That bucket is too heavy." This doesn't correspond to an SOA because the concept of "too heavy" has no fixed ranged of values.
Counterfactuals: "If I hadn't been sick I would have won." This doesn't correspond to a SOA because there there is no fact of the matter about what the world would have been like if it had been different.
Truth impredicative: "This sentence is true." This doesn't correspond to any particular SOA because if it's true, it's true and if it's false, it's false. There is no distinct and consistent SOA that it could be referring to. The Liar is another example of the same thing: "This sentence is false", except in this case instead of two possible SOAs, there are none.
Note that you can assign truth values to pseudo-propositions, and this is often done either by convention or definition, but they aren't true or false in the sense that a normal proposition is.
So, my purpose here is not to push my own version of a theory of truth; it's to try to clarify my point which is this: there is nothing that the Liar is about. For a proposition to be true, it has to be about something distinct from the very truth of the proposition itself, it has to be about something that, in some sense, exists prior to the proposition. The Liar isn't about anything, so why would philosophers think it's a problem that it is not consistently either true nor false?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The issue with The Liar is that it contradicts the common sense expectation that a syntactical correct assertion having meaning (but we know of some examples of "correct" ones lacking meaning) is either true or false: "It is raining", "I'm blonde", "What I'm saying now is true",...
Formal semantics as envisioned by Tarski (1933) developed a rigorous approach to meaning, at least applicable to regimented languages, based on the Aristotelian analysis of truth when applied to sentences:

A true sentence is one which says that the state of affairs is so and so, and the state of affairs indeed is so and so.

But when we analyze philosophically the common sense expectation, we find a lot of issues about bivalence, truth as correspondence meaning,.. and this is the reason why so simple a puzzle is relevant.
A relevant point is connected to Lawvere's generalization of Cantor "diagonal argument": Lawvere stress the fact that well-known arguments: Cantor, Russell, Gödel, are based on diagonalization when in fact there are two "pillars": diagonalization and fixed-point.
According to Lawvere the fixed-point is the "productive part" of those arguments:

"this diagonal argument has been traced (by philosophers) back to ancient philosophers who used something like it to mystify people with the Liar’s paradox."

See also Yonofsky (2003).
The connection between Liar and fixed-point has been considered also by Kripke (1975):

Kripke consider "ordinary assertions involving the notion of falsity" "point[ing] up an important lesson: it would be fruitless to look for an intrinsic criterion that will enable us to sieve out-as meaningless, or ill-formed-those sentences which lead to paradox."
"The moral: an adequate theory must allow our statements involving the notion of truth to be risky: they risk being paradoxical if the empirical facts are extremely (and unexpectedly) unfavorable. There can be no syntactic or semantic "sieve" that will winnow out the "bad" cases while preserving the "good ones."

Kripke solution to overcome Tarski's problem: the creation of a theory that contains its own truth predicate avoiding the costruction of a paradoxical statement asserting its own falsehood, is to allow some statements to lack truth values:that is, there can be truth-value gaps.
See also Gila Sher, A new defense of Tarski’s solution to the liar paradox (2023) for a philosophical defense of Tarski’s hierarchical solution to the Liar paradox, that is usually viewed as ad hoc.

A (sort of) conclusion:

diagonalization and fixed-point are productive tools for mathematics, but we don't have to identify them with self-reference. Lawvere generalization is fundamental because helps us to disentangle e.g. Gödel's theorem from self-reference (and thus, according to a common held view it hides some sort of paradox):  it shows that "there really are no paradoxes. There are limitations".

Self-reference and the Liar are issues for regimented languages, at least until we do not have a solution that is not ad hoc. But regimented languages are ad hoc: no one thinks seriously to replace natural language with predicate logic.

Self-reference is an issue for philosophers? At least for analytic ones: yes. The "empirically minded" philosopher who studies language tries to explain (or, at least, elucidate) how language works, with the related issues concerning meaning and truth. But natural language is not "closed": it is not a formal system, nor even a proof system. Concepts like completeness and consistency (and maybe neither bivalence) do not apply to natural language [see A.Tarski, The Semantic Conception of Truth and The Foundations of Semantics (1944): "the problem of consistency has no exact meaning with respect to everyday language."]


If we follow this approach, maybe the solution is simply that the Liar is like "Colourless green ideas...": it is a syntactically correct sentence that does not have meaning (it does not express a thought).
A similar approach to the Liar has been suggested by Peter Dillard, mimicking Wittgenstein's approach to rules (Phi.Inv. §201):

there is a way of grasping a rule which is not an interpretation, but which is exhibited in what we call "obeying the rule" and "going against it" in actual cases.

Maybe a speaker can "understand" the Liar (grasp its meaning) without assessing its truth value; see Aaron Sloman, Tarski, Frege and the Liar Paradox (Philosophy, 1971).

Perhaps the "confusion" is like this: We normally see Reference as a mapping from a domain of sentences (propositions, whatever) to a domain of possible facts (the world as collection of possible facts). Truth then is a mapping of these relations to {0, 1}. But then we need to reconsider, since those mappings are themselves part of "the world". Is that what the "fixed-point" aspect alludes to? (In a Wittgensteinian/Piercean approach I could say that we're dealing with an "index", rather than "icon" or "token", which signifies not by convention but by direct causal link between objects?)

"Lawvere stress the fact that well-known arguments: Cantor, Russell, Gödel, are based on diagonalization when in fact there are two "pillars": diagonalization and fixed-point." I've added https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma because I believe it's the proper article to give the sentence context. Please roll-back if I'm wrong. @mudskipper, you may be interested.

Also, added Oxford article to "regimented language". That's a useful term, indeed. The act of regimentation is ad hoc because it is done based on our intuitions of natural language.

@JD - Thanks - I noticed you added the link. When I studied math and logic, category theory was never spoken of, so that's a a big gap in my background knowledge. (Unfortunately, the wiki article is unreadable and pretty useless -- not because of the formalism but because crucial concepts like "graph formula" remain undefined...) (The Lawvere article itself also presupposes too much existing knowledge... I guess I'll have to read Lawvere's introduction to category theory first.)

@mudskipper Category theory is often overtouted and mystified. It's nothing more than using a graph theoretic notation to abstract formal structures in language such as sets or functions. Where as set theory and function theory rely on linearized language to convey an ontology and process, category theory just uses dots and arrows (and a highly abstract vocabulary to lead one on a chase of arrows down a hole into Wonderland, naturally...) ; )

One way to understand the meaning of the Liar is from the point of view of biology. When a moth displays a snake's eye on its wings, this mimicry is a message to its predators, saying "I am a snake!". But in fact, as we know, that moth is not a snake. Both moth and moth-eating bird "speak the same language", but the message is a self-referential lie, a precursor of the Liar. For a bird that eats moths, but is wary of snakes, this kind of message is problematic since it makes it more likely that it will skip this meal. For the moth, the lie is advantageous, as long as it works. Birds that always fall for the lie, might stop eating the moths. If that happens, the message may become meaningless. If the depicted snakes die out, or disappear, the message may also change its meaning or become pointless.
Almost any communication between prey and predator, either in the form of morphology (mimicry) or behavior (e.g. feints, distractions, stalking), will be a variant of the Liar. A cat sitting motionless next to a mouse hole is saying "I am not here". The mouse sitting frozen stiff just inside its hole is saying the same thing (in silence). In a stand- (or sit-)off between Liar and Liar, the first one to abandon the Liar loses. (Though mice are wily and some cats really a bit stupid.)
There are other places where the Liar shows up. For instance in graphical art. Think of Magritte's This Is Not a Pipe (wrapped in Foucault's analysis). Or think of NOT ART.
Is NOT ART a statement? Isn't all art also a statement? And if it's a statement, it's obviously self-referential. So, as graphical, conceptual art, it's about as close you can get to the purely verbal Liar. -- But isn't it obviously true? So, perhaps it is more analogous to the anti-Liar statement "this is true"? For someone for who art should hang on a wall or in a museum, this may be so. For someone who appreciates Dada or conceptual art, this is pure art. But then it can only be a variant of the Liar - an anonymous, minimalistic, unpretentious moment of wonder. -- And really, it is itself, an object of art and not an object of art, by being just this.A
The Liar has an obvious, intended meaning, which is to say that it, itself, is a false statement. What is says makes it equivalent to a logical contradiction. This makes it "dangerous" (or "fascinating" or "mysterious" depending on your point of view)B if we only want to catch truths and not be caught off guard by falsehoods. But
any paradox is a driver of intellectual (or artistic) development, so rather than scolding the Liar for being "an abuse", why not praise it for being a primordial, extremely important, very common form of communication and -- in its final human linguistic form -- a trigger for creative responses?

A. What about music? Are there any analogies to the Liar there? In music the concept of "statement" starts to sound a bit different, since instrumental music is not usually considered to make any statements (unless perhaps in impressionistic music), let alone self-referential ones. But if we look at high-level analogies... Music does "reference" other music (by quoting parts of its melodies, for instance) and it references itself continuously (by repetition). It "comments on" the music of other composers (simply by being in the same style for instance or by defiantly selecting a totally different style). So, what would be an analogy to the Liar? Perhaps John Cage's 4'33'', which was "was met with shock and widespread controversy" when it was first performed? Since, in a way, 4'33'' being silent (in the context of our musical traditions) says "This is not silence". (For a fun little interview in which he refers to Kant, see John Cage About Silence.)
B. Another useful term to describe it is of course "useful". The Liar has proven to be extremely useful since it can be thought of as the template for Gödel's incompleteness theorem. We now have a much clearer understanding of some aspects of semantics - and know in particular that "truth" cannot be fully captured by "provability".

Yet another variation on the theme of the Liar is Marvin Minsky's Useless Machine, a little gadget whose only function, once turned on, is to turn itself off.
Is it really that "useless", an "abuse" of serious mechanics and engineering ingenuity? In the biology of multicellular organisms (like us) there is apoptosis, programmed cell death, which can also be seen as a variant of the Liar (it says "this cell should die!" in the language of biochemistry) and which is needed for regular development and to prevent cancers.

You ask:

Why is the Liar a problem?

and state:

It will be easiest to explain in terms of a correspondence theory of truth based on states of affairs, although I don't think this theory or states of affairs are really essential to the point.

Largely in the spirit of a correspondence theory of truth, the liar paradox is like any abstraction that seems to be irrelevant to states of affair in the physical world. After all, a paradox by definition is something that cannot be in its fundamental sense, like a square circle. Therefore, it's easy to dismiss it as a silly confusion of language that has no bearing on what is true about the world.
But there's another sense of truth that revolves not around the empirical character of events that go on external and around us, but regarding the coherence of claims: the coherent theory of truth. Instead of an empirical character or claims about what is physically sensible, these propositions are used in the rational space of thought and are the stuff of introspection. In fact, the category of paradoxes revolve around a rather spectacular failure of propositions to cohere in a systematic way with themselves, which is distinct from most claims that fail to cohere with other claims.
Thus, it sets off our cognitive dissonance to experience that an ostensibly meaningful proposition seems to vacillate between two exclusionary truth values (under classical logic, of course), and demonstrate a schizophrenic character. This problem then snowballs into the more useful realm of epistemic logic, since besides the logical problems of contradiction, we also have to deal with doxastic challenges. Is it true we believe the liar's proposition? Does the liar believe the liar's proposition? Do we reject the liar's proposition? Do we believe the liar believes the liar's proposition? The Liar's Paradox, therefore, challenges both our intuitions of truth and our certainty about otherwise reliable knowledge about propositions and agents.
So, not only do we struggle with the logical system and clarifying values of truth and falsity of propositions, but we also struggle with propositional attitudes. And clearly that's an uncomfortable situation given that our evolution predisposes us to prioritizing theory of mind. Which, of course, is what paradoxes and koans are meant to do. They are meant to challenge our introspective selves to force us to think carefully about what we believe. And in that sense, while we could simply discard paradoxes as irrelevant and pointless curious puzzles, we can also see there is an epistemic cost because they challenge our reliabilist intuitions of knowledge(SEP), and force us to reassess our own metaepistemic theories. And it is not easy to give up the comforts of conviction.

I agree with you. For me, the liar paradox is useful in purely formal disciplines. However, semantically speaking, it’s an abuse of language.
But, your solution:

For a proposition to be true, it has to be about something that, in some sense, exists prior to the proposition.

is not tenable. The concept of «priority» is vague. Yes, it's right to say that every proposition should be about something, but you didn't show why a proposition should not be about itself.
The paradox presents a proposition P that says, "P is false" .The problem here is that to understand the meaning of "P", you must first understand the meaning of the proposition "P is false". To grasp that meaning, you need to understand the meaning of "P" again. This leads to an infinite regress of understanding, which suggests that we don’t actually comprehend the meaning of P.
Thus, there isn't a meaningful problem to begin with.

https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/688:_Self-Description seems perfectly meaningful to me (and accurate).

I don't think the problem with the Liar is self-reference or self-representation. The image in your link shows that it's possible. The problem with it is the infinite regress of understanding.
The first panel is defined as the panel that depicts the amount of black and white in the whole picture Pic.
Now, what is the definition of Pic? I can define it as a picture that has the size S to which you internet link refer.
Thus, understanding the meaning of "Pic" doesn't depend on understanding the meaning of "panel1" or "panel2", ect.
I hope you can see the difference.

I don't think that self-reference by itself is problematic either - just self-reference + negation (where self-reference includes making semantics explicit). But if self-reference is not the problem, then there is also no infinite regress. The predicate "is not true" is attributed to something ("P") that is right in front of our eyes.

What is before our eyes in the sign 'P', not its meaning.
The meaning of 'P' is composite, it contain more that one concept, similar to the meaning of the sign 'woman' that contain the concept (human) and (female). To understand the meaning of a composite concept, you should understand beforehand the meaning of its constituents. the problem with the liar is that the concept (P) is a part of the composite meaning of (P) which is absurd, and makes it impossible to understand what we mean by 'P'.
it's like talking about something A and when you ask me what is A? I respond A = A is white

The meaning of the Liar sentence is the Liar sentence. I see meanings as objects (sometimes: observations) generated by a process of interpretation. Sometimes those objects may differ from the interpreted input (this is the usual case), here the interpreted input object (an observed sentence) is identical to the output (meaning). So, this is "circular" in a way, but I don't see that in itself as problematic. Isn't any self-reference  circular in this way?

When you speak about the sign P - "P" in the way you're using it, wouldn't you say that its meaning is its reference? "P" is used as a proper name, not as a composite term. It's a name for the the sentence in which it is used as name. To understand a name, I only need to know what it refers to -- which in this case is that sentence...

So, I partially agree with you in so far that it is possible to see the Liar as an infinite regress - of course. But I disagree in so far that I don't think that's the real problem with it - it sort of misses the point of the paradox, is what I'm tempted to say.

I don't agree that the meaning of a term - even if it's a proper name - is its referent. you know very well the problem with this theory. To know the meaning of the term 'T' is to know what you are committed to if you suppose that some x is T.
To understand the meaning of 'P', I should know what I'm committed to when I say that something is P. Now,  the paradox tells that when you say that something is P, you should be committed that P is a proposition that contains the sign 'P' that has the meaning x or commitments (a, b, c,...) that are the very commitments I'm asking for.

for example, to know the meaning of 'Zeus', I need to know what I'm committed to if I suppose that something is Zeus, one may tell me that I should be committed to that x is a god and that is the son of such or such god.
now, you speak to me about some P. I don't understand yet its meaning, so I ask you: 'What should I commit to if I suppose that some x is P? You answer that I should be committed that x is a proposition, that x contains the sign 'p' that has a specific meaning. I ask you: "What specific meaning?" you respond: The meaning that you have been asking for!

Up to about one year ago, I would be saying the same things (!). But I'm slowly changing my pov. Imo Frege's influence here prevents us from seeing 'meaning' correctly. David Haig, in From Darwin to Derrida, is on the right track.

You are probing at one of the problems of applying classical logic to our world.  There are aspects of our world that do not fit into classical logic's two categories of "true" or "false".  This is why, for most of science, and other kinds of investigation, a four-state logic rather than a two-state logic is used:

Sufficient supporting justification to accept as a working hypothesis
Sufficient refuting justification to reject as a working hypothesis
Insufficient justification to currently evaluate the question
and Question is incoherent or faces other intrinsic logic or evaluative difficulties such that it can never be properly justified or not

You are focused on the 4th category for The Liar, which breaks the Principle of the Excluded Middle for Classical logic.  But so do the other three categories of this 4-category logic as well.  It is not a problem for you or our world that some aspects of our universe do not satisfy classical logic -- it is only a problem for advocates of classical logic as the One True Logic.

The liars paradox does not break the law of excluded middle. Fuzzy logic does not exclude the middle, but still suffers the liar. So that part of the answer is irrelevant and misleading. This answer then just repeats as in the question that it's "only a problem for advocates of classical logic", but does not answer why. So what else is this answer than a confused rant against classical logic?

@tkruse -- "neither, because of non-relevance" very explicitly breaks the law of the excluded middle.  That non-relevance, and fuzzy logic apply to our world, is extremely relevant to the OP's expressed confusion when classical logic does not work for The Liar.
